# Text file not loading information into Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, load

I'm trying to get the content from a text file into a `Listbox`, but I can't get it to work. It works fine however with a text box.

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click      
Dim filename As String  
        Dim recipereader As StreamReader  
        ofdLoad.ShowDialog()      
        filename = ofdLoad.FileName
        If filename <> "" Then  
            recipereader = File.OpenText(filename)  
            ListBox1.Text = recipereader.ReadToEnd  
            recipereader.Close()  
        End If  
    End Sub  
End Class
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text refers to something entirly different but to add items to a list box you must use: `Listbox.Items.Add(yourItems)`.

Change `ListBox1.Text = recipereader.ReadToEnd` to `ListBox1.Items.Add(recipereader.ReadToEnd)`. Remember that this will add all the text in ONE single ListBox Item.